# Exporting Pybossa results to Scifabric Enki in real time

Tags: statistics, crowdsourcing, pybossa

[Pybossa](https://github.com/Scifabric/pybossa) is a very good crowdsourcing framework that can be used for getting the responses on volunteer basis. They have the statistical analysis tool [Enki](https://github.com/Scifabric/enki) that can be used for analysis of the results that we get as responses to our experiment. Is there a way to export Pybossa results to Enki so that the results can be analyzed in real-time?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is our webhooks solution: https://github.com/Scifabric/webhooks

It uses Enki too, so you have a full example in the code to run your analysis in real-time.